# As number of detected SURF keypoints is different for each image, how to save in featurevector of fixed length?

Tags: image, matlab, feature-detection, feature-extraction, surf

The number of SURF keypoints is different for each image.
I'm storing the features for each image in different columns as

FV(N X K)=[FV_IMG1  FV_IMG2]

I tried limiting 10 best features. But ofcourse some image have below 10 features. How to deal with this variability in number of detected features? I came across normalization- I'm not sure how that is done for SURF keypoints?

Comment: You have two options main options 1) use a cell array rather than a matrix that you've shown or 2) set the "empty" values to a default value (i.e. NaN, -1, etc.).

Comment: So since the cell array has different number of items, how can I convert it later to save as .mat file

Comment: To save as a .mat file, you just save the variable like you would any other variable. You don't have to do any conversions prior to saving as a cell array.